# How to do compare a bundle with collectionassert in jUnit?

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertions

I want to make sure the below `bundles` list doesn't contain `TestFramework` bundle using jUnit assert method.

```
Bundle[] bundles = framework.getBundleContext().getBundles();
```

So I was wondering whether jUnit provides any such method to compare a bundle with List of Bundles?

Comment: Does `TestFramework`  extends `Bundle` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop through the array and use assertEquals or assertFalse (assuming you dont want to use ham as mentioned by John B).

```
for (Bundle current : bundles)
{
    assertFalse(current instanceof TestFramework);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/):

```
 Assert.assertThat(bundles, 
          CoreMatchers.not(
               IsArrayContaining.hasItemInArray(TestFramework)));
```

If you use static imports this would be:

```
 assertThat(bundles, not(hasItemInArray(myItem)));
```

If you need instance of you can use:

```
 Assert.assertThat(bundles, 
          CoreMatchers.not(
               IsArrayContaining.hasItemInArray(
                    CoreMatchers.instanceOf(TestFramework.class))));
```

[IsArrayContaining](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContaining.html)

FYI, I used `Assert.assertThat` just because it is easier but I prefer to use `MatcherAssert.assertThat` because it gives better error documentation.

**Edit** in response to DwB. I prefer `Hamcrest` because the non-Hamcrest solution presented works but in the failure case you don't get any information other than `expected false got true`. This won't tell you which element of the array fails the condition or if multiple elements failed. Once you go Hamcrest you will never go back. I never use `assertTrue`, `assertFalse` or `assertEquals` any more.